# Newbie trying to undersatand Safari CSS font-size test results

Tags: css, fonts, safari

I am trying to learn CSS.  For my testing I edit an html text file and view the result with Safari V11.0.  My project is to render for the web an old-fashioned printed report which uses fixed columns and a monospaced font.

I have some test results that I do not understand, and would appreciate your suggestions for my further study.

```
body {font: 100% Courier, monospace}
```

Does what I want; however,...

```
body {font: Courier, monospace}
```

...does not.  Safari renders my page in some proportional font.

Question 1: Why is the font-size required?

Moreover,

```
body {font: 80% Courier, monospace}
```

works, but the size of the characters is the same as 100%.

Question 2: Why is the font-size ignored?

--Gil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this link:
[W3C Font Shorthand](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp)

Because you are not using the longhand definitions like font-size and font-family, you need to follow the spec for shorthand, which says that size is one of the required attributes:

> The font shorthand property sets all the font properties in one declaration.
>
> The properties that can be set, are (in order): "font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height font-family"
>
> The font-size and font-family values are required. If one of the other values are missing, the default values will be inserted, if any.

Comment: Thanks, RussAwesome.  That's the rule I missed.  Any idea why the size doesn't seem to matter?

Comment: Hi Gil, not sure about the font size being ignored. Have a look at this fiddle where the 100% and 80% are set on two span tags and see if you can reproduce the issue using your own code so far. You may have other tags interfering with the output, so a pared down example is best.
http://jsfiddle.net/u47506x2/

Comment: Your fiddle worked as expected, thanks.  I found that text outside my table was sized as expected, but the size of text inside my table tags did not change.  I have yet to learn fiddle, so I will work on that now to show the problem.  Thanks for getting me started with these cool tools.

Comment: I made a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/GilDawson/yh0qrf9v/3/) by pasting my html file into both the HTML and CSS panels, then deleting tags it didn't like.  On Run, the code worked as expected: all text changed inside and outside the table.  I'm supposing there's something in my Safari's Preferences, maybe.

Comment: @Alohci came up with the answer on another thread: "Add <!DOCTYPE html> to the top of your file."  I never would have guessed it.  "Quirks Mode" on Wikipedia explains why.